# Htaccess : Redirect OK, but rewrite doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have fairly simply rewrite rules :

```
# Evenements URL rewrite
RewriteRule ^agenda/evenement/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ agenda/evenement/?idEvent=$2&title=$1 [R=302,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/agenda/evenement/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ en/agenda/evenement/?idEvent=$2&title=$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^en/calendar/event/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ en/calendar/event/?idEvent=$2&title=$1 [R=302,L]
```

That works out fine. But I want to rewrite, not redirect. If I remove the R=302, I get 404s automatically. Any idea why ?

Here's the full block, to see if my rules are at the wrong place (I've tried to move them around)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
# Evenements URL rewrite
RewriteRule ^agenda/evenement/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ agenda/evenement/?idEvent=$2&title=$1 [R=302,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/agenda/evenement/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ en/agenda/evenement/?idEvent=$2&title=$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^en/calendar/event/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ en/calendar/event/?idEvent=$2&title=$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks !

Comment: specify exact script filename in the replacement path, otherwise it will get directory index in the next round.

Comment: Is this wordpress or some other CMS framework?

Comment: Wordpress yes. I've tried putting rewrite rules in this form instead : RewriteRule ^agenda/evenement/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?pagename=evenement&idEvent=$2&title=$1 [L]
But they the page behind doesn't get the GET parameters. Looks like the problem is deeper on wordpress than on regular sites !